# SwitchMap result from Angular Redux Store

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs

I have a redux store where I keep a series of values, in this case partners that look like:

```
partners: [ {id: 1, name: 'partner 1', partnerCode: 'ABC123', ... }, {id: 2, name: 'partner 2', partnerCode: 'CDE567', ...}, ...];
```

I fetch the partners using:

```
this.store.select('partnerFunc').subscribe(data  => {
  this.partner = data.partners.find(t => t.partnerId === this.id);
});
```

I want to be able to perform and action after I get the result back, make an API call based on the partner code that is returned.

```
this.dataService.getUsers(partnerCode).subscribe(data => { this.users = data; });
```

I think I need to use switchMap as once I have the relevant partner I know long want to subscribe to the redux store. I have tried lots of combinations and looked everywhere here but can't seem to figure out the format.

This is the best I have come up with to try and explain what I am trying to do:

```
this.store.select('partnerFunc').pipe(switchMap(result => {
  return result.partners.find(t => t.partnerId === this.id);
})).subscribe(value => {
  this.dataService.getUsersForPartner(value.partnerId).subscribe(data => {
    this.users = data;
  })
});
```

but the result on the first line is throwing an error that:

```
Argument of type '(result: State) => IPartner' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: State, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my best guess from what you've described and the code you've shown here:

```ts
this.store.select('partnerFunc').pipe(
  map(result => 
    result.partners.find(t => t.partnerId === this.id)
  ),
  switchMap(({partnerId}) => 
    this.dataService.getUsersForPartner(partnerId)
  )
).subscribe(data => 
  this.users = data
);
```

The point of a higher-order operator is that it manages subscriptions for you, which is how you avoid nesting subscriptions (and avoid a whole class of possible bugs). You'll notice here how you only need to subscribe once.